# To what size should i increase the size to avoid perm gen error?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, size, permgen

While installing google app engine for eclipse i get `perm gen error`. I read that you need to increase the size of `perm gen` for eclipse from the config or ini file packed with eclipse. Currently it looks like this :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m  
-Xmx512m
```

At how many places do i have to do the edit ? Where do i need to add ? And does `256 M` mean MB ? To what size should i increase the size ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one at the end of the ini file:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Keep making this bigger until the problem goes away - try 128M first and see how it goes.

Yes, 256M means "256 megabyes". You may also use `G` for gigabytes.

Comment: actually `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m` allocates the PermSize.. If it is causing a problem increase it to 348m and test it out.

Comment: @Ravi That's for the launcher, not the IDE. The "launcher" VM settings are for the JVM(s) that get started by the IDE, like when you run a unit test or a `main()` etc. The IDE itself has its own different (and usually larger) VM settings that don't have the `--launcher.` prefix, like the last ones in OP's posted file contents